# Перечисления с двумя переменными

Tags: java, enum, калькулятор

Нужно чтобы в основной программе обрабатывались римские цифры, делаю это через перечисление римских цифр. Как сделать так, что зная nummersrim я могла вывести на экран numbersar?

```
public enum Rim {
    I("I", 1), II("II", 2), III("III", 3), IV("IV", 4), V("V", 5), VI("VI", 6), VII("VII", 7), VIII("VIII", 8), IX("IX", 9), X("X", 10);
    private int numbersar;
    private String numbersrim;
    Rim(String numbersrim, int numbersar){
        this.numbersar = numbersar;
        this.numbersrim = numbersrim;
    }
    public String getNumbersrim(){
        return numbersrim;
    }

    public int getNumbersar(){
        return numbersar;
    }


}
```

Comment: Домашку нужно делать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае достаточно вызвать метод `getNumbersar` для данного экземпляра `Rim`:

```java
for (Rim roman : Rim.values()) {
    System.out.println(roman + ": " + roman.getNumbersar());
}
```

Результат:

```
I: 1
II: 2
III: 3
IV: 4
V: 5
VI: 6
VII: 7
VIII: 8
IX: 9
X: 10
```

---

Также можно упростить перечисление, переиспользовав стандартный метод `Enum::ordinal`, тогда не понадобятся отдельные поля для представления римских и арабских чисел, но потребуется ввести фиктивный "ноль":

```java
enum Roman {
    ZERO, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X;
}

// ...
System.out.println(Roman.I + ": " + Roman.I.ordinal());
// -> I: 1
```

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы в основной программе выводилось только число, без обозначения римской цифры, нужно составить калькулятор, где вызывается при вводе римской цифры арабская цифра, пытаюсь это через перечисление сделать

Comment: Повторю ответ: для "вывода" обычного числового значения (которое называют арабским, хотя оно скорее индийское) достаточно использовать соответствующий метод перечисления: `Rim::getNumbersar` в вашей реализации или обычный `Roman::ordinal`.  В чём именно у вас проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere Man предложил отличную идею использовать `ordinal()`, позволю себе немного оптимизировать его решение:

```
enum Rim {
    I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ordinal() + 1 + "";
    }
}
```

**как это работает:**
в каждом `enum` есть встроенная функция `ordinal()` которая возвращает порядковый номер константы, которые начинаются с 0.

```
I.ordinal() ///< == 0
II.ordinal() ///< == 1
```

поэтому нам надо добавить 1 и пустую строку чтобы сконвертировать результат в строку.

```
System.out.println(Rim.II); ///< "2"
System.out.println(Rim.IX); ///< "9"
```

Comment: Странная "оптимизация"... Каждый раз добавлять единицу...

Comment: @XelaNimed, оптимизация структуры, направлена на устранение необходимости ввода искусственной константы ZERO. К тому же добавление единицы несущественно по сравнению с преобразованием числа в строку с точки зрения производительности.

Comment: Так в чём оптимизация-то заключалась? В удалении члена перечисления ZERO (что в принципе может пригодится в вычислениях) и добавлении единицы? К тому-же возвращаемый тип - строка, которую нужно будет для вычислений преобразовывать к числу. На мой взгляд, [вариант Nowhere Man](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1536848/182750) лучше. Это просто моё мнение и я бы так не делал, по выше указанным причинам.